# How can I get a non-inclusive subset of a List?

Tags: java, arraylist, filter

Do Java lists have a method for selecting a subset of indices from a List?

For example, the list `[a, b, c, d, e, f, g]` with input `[1, 4, 5]` should output `[a, d, e]`.

Comment: I'm using java 7, but what is the java 8 way?

Comment: There is no such method in Collections class for this but you can get it by using a simple loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty easy in Java 8, just make sure to use the stream on the *indices*, not on the objects, and use [`.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-);

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");
  List<Integer> indices = Arrays.asList(1, 3);

  List<String> resultList = indices.stream()
                  .map(i -> stringList.get(i))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());

  System.out.println(resultList);
}
```

It's not that hard in Java 7 either:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c", "d");
  List<Integer> indices = Arrays.asList(1, 3);

  List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<>();

  for(int i : indices) {
    resultList.add(stringList.get(i));
  }

  System.out.println(resultList);  
}
```

In both cases the output is:

```
[b, d]
```

Comment: I was looking for a native way to do it, this is exactly what I am using

Answer (score 0):

Use only one loop with `LinkedHashMap`, as there is not such particular method to get a subset of list (*index-wise*) in **Collection** class.

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Character> ls = new ArrayList<Character>();
        ls.add('a');
        ls.add('b');
        ls.add('c');
        ls.add('d');
        ls.add('e');
        ls.add('f');
        ls.add('g');
//EDIT
    int subIndex[] = new int[] { 1, 4, 5 };
    Map<Integer, Character> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < subIndex.length; i++) {
        result.put(i, ls.get(subIndex[i] - 1));
    }
    System.out.println(result.values());    
}
```

**Output:**
`[a, d, e]`

I hope this will help.

Comment: Actually, I think the output of this is `ade`, not `[a, d, e]`

Comment: @durron597, Thanks for raising this concern. Output of this is either 'ade' or     a d e(all are in different lines(println())).

Comment: @durron597, Please check now. Thanks for mentioning.